# Filter selections from JSON in Angular based on array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter, angular-filters

So my data-set looks like this *(much more stats behind it but lets keep this simple)*:

```
$scope.peopleData = [
  {"name": "Name1", "img": "name1Img.png"},
  {"name": "Name2", "img": "name2Img.png"}...
];
```

Doing just fine displaying all of the items via a simple:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in peopleData">
  <img src="img/people/{{person.img}}" alt="{{person.name}}" />
</div>
```

Now let's say I'm storing friends and have a different section that only lists specific people. Take, for example, an array such as:

```
var friends = ["Name4", "Name9"];
```

How would I go about writing a function that would return:

```
$scope.friends = [
  {"name": "Name4", "img": "name4Img.png"},
  {"name": "Name9", "img": "name9Img.png"}...
];
```

Essentially, I want to search through all of the peopleData and return a smaller array based upon several values contained within an array?

Surely there has to be a simple method to use .filter() to find multiple  strings as acceptable values?

```
$scope.friendData = peopleData.filter(friends);
```

I think I'm just missing a small piece here...

Comment: `var friends = ["Name4", "Name9"];`. There is no space before digit ?

Comment: Have you tried using `filter` with `indexOf`?

Comment: @Rayon There will be no spaces in the fields. Sorry for the quick typeup. Editing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [**`Array#indeOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to test the value in `array`

```js
var friends = [{
  "name": "Name4",
  "img": "name4Img.png"
}, {
  "name": "Name9",
  "img": "name9Img.png"
}, {
  "name": "Name10",
  "img": "name10Img.png"
}];
var friendsArr = ["Name4", "Name9"];
var friendData = friends.filter(function(item) {
  return friendsArr.indexOf(item.name) !== -1; //`item.name` exists in `friendsArr`
});
console.log(friendData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFriendsDetails()
{
    var friends = ["Name4", "Name9"];
    var friendsDetails  = [];

    for(var i = 0; i<friends.length;i++)
    {
       var friend = friends[i];
       friendsDetails.push({"name":friend, "img":(friend.toLowerCase()+"Img.png")});
    }

    return friendsDetails;
}
```

**[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cucom24c/)**

Answer (score 0):

For a greater data amount, you could use a hash table for faster lookup

```js
var $scope = {},
    friends = ["Name4", "Name9"];

$scope.peopleData = [{ "name": "Name1", "img": "name1Img.png" }, { "name": "Name4", "img": "name4Img.png" }],

$scope.friendData = $scope.peopleData.filter(function (friends) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);
    friends.forEach(function (a) { hash[a] = true; });
    return function (a) { return hash[a.name]; };
}(friends));

console.log($scope.friendData);
```

In ES6 you could filter it with `Array.includes`.

```
$scope.friendData = peopleData.filter(a => friends.includes(a.name));
```